# plotting non-continuous functions in R without vertical lines

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting some functions in R. Some of them aren't continuous and I get a vertical line between the diferent curve components. I really need to get this vertical line out (It makes the function look like a no-function and I don't want that).

So, how can I do that? Right now, I'm using two vectors `x` and`y` and doing `plot(x,y,type = "l")` so R doesn't understand where there is a discontinuity. But I didn't find a better way.

Comment: If you need concrete help you'll need to provide [a more concrete, reproducible example (click here for tips)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the optimum solution, but if the number of functions is small you could split them leaving the continous parts, then just use `plot` for the first one and add the other with `lines`. e.g.:

```
  x <- seq(1,3,1)
  y <- sqrt(x) 
  x2 <-  seq(3,6,1)
  y2 <- runif(4)

  plot(y ~ x, type = "l",col = 2 , ylim = c(0,2) , xlim = c(0,6))
  lines(y2 ~ x2, col = 2)
```

Comment: If you use `lines` instead of `points` you can skip the `type = "l"` argument.